# R: background or inserted image and text in lattice

Tags: r, lattice

I'd like to insert a watermark onto a `lattice` image. In `ggplot2`, I simply used the the `annotate` or `annotation_custom` options to place a logo image and a text below the logo in a corner of the plot. Is there a similar possibility in `lattice`? Or as an alternative - is it possible to use an image as background of the plot?

Comment: Is this an alternative to the recent ggplot question?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik: No, as I'd like to use the logo in `lattice` in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what Deepayan Sarkar offered on Rhelp a couple of years ago to a similar question:

```
barchart(variety ~ yield | site, data = barley, groups = year, layout = c(3,1), 
         page = function(n) { 
              grid.text(label = "Privileged and Confidential \nDRAFT", 
              x = unit(0.01, "npc"),
              y = unit(0.95, "npc"), 
              just = c("left", "center")) })
```

Obviously you would also need to use grid graphics functions to place the logo, (but you haven't offered one to work with. The first two lines of this next code was found at @baptiste's [blog page](http://blog.ggplot2.org/post/23537012922/adding-watermarks-to-plots) cited today on SO.) The second two lines were adapted from [Paul Murrell's article](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2011-1/RJournal_2011-1_Murrell.pdf) in last years "R Journal" found with Rseek.org:

```
library(png)
m <- readPNG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.png", package="png"), FALSE)
rimg <- as.raster(m)
grid.raster(rimg, x=.05, y=.9, just="top", width=.1)
```

[image]

Comment: Simply replacing the text by the logo (e.g. replacing `"Privileged and Confidential \nDraft"` by `m`) simply places a `0` into the upper left corner. Do you know how I can insert an image instead of text?

Comment: I'm not able to offer a tested reply without an image to work with. That's why I offered the link to the png package.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with using the Rlogo image that you cited in your answer as an example?